# Keep State of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I have a gridview and I'm trying to keep the state of. Currently I have it where the user can edit inline( from within the gridview). Regularly I got this working:

```
protected void GridViewTower_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Set the edit index.
    GridViewTower.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    //Bind/Re-LoadData data to the GridView control.
    LoadData();
    Populate();
}

protected void GridViewTower_CancelEditRow(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Reset the edit index.
    GridViewTower.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind/Re-LoadData data to the GridView control.
    LoadData();
    Populate();
}
```

Problem is, I have 3 other features such sorting, dropdown that filters gridview, and a button search which also filters the girdview. When inline editing within any 3 of those modes, I can't control the state in which the gridview is in. Inside my gridview tag, I have both EnableViewState and ViewStateMode set to true.

How can I keep the state of the gridview within these modes?

---

```
public void LoadData()
{

    if (Session["GridView"] != null)
    {

        GridViewTower.DataSource = Session["GridView"];

        GridViewTower.DataBind();

        //Response.Redirect("TowerManagement.aspx"); //

        //Session["GridView"] = null;
    }
    else
    {

        WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();

        var tower = (from t in context.Towers
                     where t.isDeleted == false
                     select new
                     {
                         t.TowerId,
                         t.TowerName,
                         RangeName = t.Range.RangeName

                     }).ToList();

        GridViewTower.DataSource = tower;
        GridViewTower.DataBind();

        ViewState["Sort"] = 0;
    }
}

protected void Gridview_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{


    WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();

    var towers = (from t in context.Towers
                  where t.isDeleted == false
                  select new
                  {
                      t.TowerId,
                      t.TowerName,
                      rangeName = t.Range.RangeName
                  }).ToList();

    DataTable gridviewTable = towers.CopyToDataTable();

    gridviewTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

    GridViewTower.DataSource = gridviewTable;

    GridViewTower.DataBind();

    Session["GridView"] = GridViewTower.DataSource;

}
```

Comment: I would suggest to keep the values for sorting, filter and search in three hidden fields outside the gridview. In LoadData() check this values and refine the datasource before binding the gridview.

Comment: Just a thought, but is it possible to store the datasource in a viewstate object? Something like: **ViewState[Gridview.Datasource,"currentGridView"];**

Comment: It is possible but I would not suggest saving datasource in viewstate. Each postback would send huge viewstate data to server. 1) I would use hiddenfield to store some values and requery the datasource in each postback. 2) In worst case I would save the source to Session rather than viewstate.

Comment: @afzalulh I not quite sure how to do 1), but I'm trying 2). So it seems to keep the state of the gridview, but when I try to edit, it won't update db. I'm not sure why. I have session variable on the bottom of each the 3 features. **Session["GridView"] = GridViewTower.DataSource;** And then in the LoadData method I check if the session is null. If not, I use the gridview session to bind to.

Comment: You have to save the underlying source (e.g. datatable, dataview) to session, not GridVew.DataSource. Post the code for LoadData(); Populate(); and sorting/filtering data, it will be easier to suggest anything.

Comment: @afzalulh I added my LoadData() and Sort() as to what I'm trying. So what I found out was it is saving, but just not showing automatically like it was before. I have a clear or reset button that sets the Session variable to null and call the LoadData(). So thats how I confirm it actually updated.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store whole table in the `Session` or `ViewState`. Just store values of SortExpression, SortOrder etc. Here's an example how you can do it.

In my code I have added two private properties to store sortorder and sortexpression:

```
private string SortOrder
{
    get
    {
        // Toggle order after sorting
        string _order = "ASC";//Default
        if( ViewState["SortOrder"] != null && ViewState["SortOrder"].ToString() =="DESC")
        {
            _order = "DESC";
            ViewState["SortOrder"] = "ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["SortOrder"] = "DESC";
        }
        return _order;
    }
    set
    {
        string _order = value.ToLower() == "descending"? "DESC" : "ASC";
        ViewState["SortOrder"] = _order;
    }
}


private string SortExpression
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["SortExpression"] != null ? ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() : "";
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = value;
    }
}
```

I have changed your GridView_Sort method to store the sort expression and sort order in newly added properties and called LoadData() method:

```
protected void Gridview_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    SortExpression = e.SortExpression;
    //Disabled sort direction to enable toggling
    //SortOrder = e.SortDirection.ToString();

    LoadData();
}
```

The LoadData() method will be called from many places, whenever we want to load data into GridView. So I have changed it to this:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();

    var towers = (from t in context.Towers
                  where t.isDeleted == false
                  select new
                  {
                      t.TowerId,
                      t.TowerName,
                      rangeName = t.Range.RangeName
                  }).ToList();



    DataTable gridviewTable = new DataTable();
    gridviewTable.Columns.Add("TowerId");
    gridviewTable.Columns.Add("TowerName");
    gridviewTable.Columns.Add("rangeName");

    foreach (var t in towers)
    {
        gridviewTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { t.TowerId, t.TowerName, t.rangeName });
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortExpression))
    {
        gridviewTable.DefaultView.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", SortExpression, SortOrder);
        gridviewTable = gridviewTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
    }

    GridViewTower.DataSource = gridviewTable;
    GridViewTower.DataBind();
}
```

Initially I call the `LoadData()` method in Page_Load() :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
           LoadData();
      }
 }
```

You can download the test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0LTJzZktMYm1RdFE/edit?usp=sharing).